# Batch file to concatenate multiple csv files into a single csv with the one header

Tags: batch-file

I need to merge multiple .csv into one, each .csv file has header (2 lines) as below;

```
Row#1 SWG   SWG report  RequestReport   1.1 2022-10-30T20:00:00Z to 2022-10-31T20:00:00Z                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Row#2 RequestID RequestDate ID  LocalizedRequestDate    ApplicationName OverallRcode
```

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem configure paths
    set "source=E:\Guest\*.csv"
    set "target=E:\Guest\SWG\Report_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~-4%.csv

    >"%target%" (
        for %%a in ("%source%") do (
            set "headerRow="
            <"%%~fa" (
                for /l %%h in (1 1 10) do if not defined headerRow set /p "headerRow="
                findstr "^"
            )
        )
    )
```

I need to keep only 1 header (2nd Row) and the data from .csv files in the destination file.

The above code is merging the files, also deleted the 1st header from each file but includes the 2nd header of each .csv file, how can I eliminate it?

Comment: So you appear to have a TSV, _(Tab Separated Values)_, file; is that correct? Can you please also explain why there are a whole lot of empty fields in each of those two 'header' records?

Comment: @Compo, Yes it is TSV, there are no empty fields in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem configure paths
set "source=E:\Guest\*.csv"
set "target=E:\Guest\SWG\Report_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~-4%.csv
set "file1="

>"%target%" (
for %%b in ("%source%") do (
 if defined file1 (
  for /f "usebackqskip=2delims=" %%e in ("%%b") do echo %%e
 ) else (
  for /f "usebackqskip=1delims=" %%e in ("%%b") do echo %%e
 )
 set "file1=N"
)
)
```

Using `file1` as a flag; force it to undefined, skip the first line of the first file, set it to defined, skip the first 2 lines of the remaining files.

Comment: no output is generated by using the above, I want to skip the first line of the first file, skip the first 2 lines of the remaining files.

Comment: There was a `)` missing at the end - now added

Comment: Thanks @Magoo, but still having challenges to produce output.

Comment: Without a specific report of the challenges, I can only guess at a solution. This routine worked for me.